# Drupal - dynamic options for text_list field

Tags: forms, dynamic, combobox, drupal-7

I have a custom node type for which I want to have a field that uses a special combobox based on `list_text`. When one chooses the type `list_text` it is normally possible to enter a static list of selectable texts, however, I want this list to be dynamic, i.e. based on the results of a `db_query`. What is the best way to do this using Drupal 7?

A simple example for clarification: A node of this custom type X contains a field that points to another node, so whenever a node of type X is created I want a combobox that contains all other nodes.

(Best solution would be to only display the combobox during node creation, and no longer during edit. But I could also live with it if the combobox was shown during the edit as well.)

I have tried to customize `options_select` by defining my own data type and implementing `hook_options_list` accordingly. The combobox was displayed during creation with the correct values, however,  I could not save it.. I have no idea what went wrong there, but on the first submit it would change to a different theme, and when I tried again I got an internal server error. Am I on the right track at all with defining a completely new data type for the field? there surely must be a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial linked by [allegroconmolto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/579325/allegroconmolto) sent me on the right way. Thanks for that.

Here's the simpler way of doing it: [tutorial](http://groups.drupal.org/node/71588)

Basically, it is, as I assumed, a common problem and hence a simple solution for it was included in the `webform` module by now. It provides a `hook_webform_select_options_info` which can be used to register a callback method. The callback method is then called each time a corresponding option select of a webform is shown, so that you can easily fill it with the results of a `dbquery` or anything else. Works like a charm and takes next to no time to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that you don't need a new datatype. Here's [a good tutorial on how to do this](http://www.commercialprogression.com/blog/drupal-webforms-with-dynamic-select-boxes-tutorial). It's not specifically for D7 but I didn't see much that wasn't still applicable. There may be a better way to do it in D7 specifically but I would love to know it too if so :)

Comment: thanks for the tutorial link. It did send me on the right track and I indeed found a much simpler way now to do it using the `webform` module.